# Execv : How to make an argv builder

Tags: c

I want to build a buffer `char *argv[]` for exec.

I have a **struct cmd** which contains all the data about the command to run :

```
struct cmd {
    int argc;
    string *argv;
}

struct string {
    int length;
    char *value;
}
```

Example : I want to run `rm file1 file2 file3`

My cmd struct will look like this :

```
struct cmd {
    argc = 4; // Number of args, we have 4
    string *argv {
        argv[0].length = 2 // length of rm
        argv[0].val = "rm" // the first arg

        argv[1].length = 5 // length of file1
        argv[1].val = "file1" // the second arg

        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to run `execvp (const char *file, char *const argv[])` using my command struct.

Here is what i tried to do

```
char **command_buf = malloc(cmd->argc * sizeof(char *));
for (int i = 0; i < (int)cmd->argc; i++) {
    command_buf[i] = malloc(cmd->argv[i].length);
    strcat(command_buf[i], cmd->argv[i].value);
}
```

But I have no idea what I'm supposed to do next to achieve a functional execvp.

PS : How would I print the buffer command_buf to keep debugging ?

Comment: `strcat(command_buf[i],` That is invalid. The buffer is not initialized and is very likely not holding a valid string that could be used for `strcat`. You should use `strcpy` instead. Or combine `malloc` and `strcat` and use `strdup` instead if available.

Comment: `malloc(cmd->argc *` That is not sufficient. You need to add a `NULL` as last element in your array of string pointers.

Comment: Thanks ! But if i use strcpy, that will override my string right ? I have no idea for making strdup work though... Can you write an example please ?

Comment: For the malloc, thank you, I'll change that. I was actually wondering how it was possible to know the length of an array without the last element being null (or a specific value).

Comment: There is nothing you would overwrite with `strcpy`. You are using a different pointer for each string in your loop. And if I mention "string" I am talking about C strings, not that strange `struct string` that you have defined.